# Laptop unable to detect Gionee E6

Tags: usb-debugging

I wanted to debug an Android app on my Ginonee e6. But when I connect it through USB cable, the device is not detected. 
Last time I had faced same issue with Samsung Galaxy Y and installing Kies solved the problem
But for `Gionee E6`, nothing works, I have `google-usb` drivers installed; still my phone is not detected. I have switched ON the `USB-Debugging` option in the settings
Please help.

[image]

Comment: have you tried plugging it into a different USB port?

Comment: @geffchang No luck, with different USB port.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install the correct drivers for the device. I'm not familiar with the device in question, but it seems that there are two drivers available on the [Gionee Mobile India](http://gionee.co.in/technical-support/) site. Try installing one of the drivers there and then connect your device again.